# CSS - two divs are on top of each other instead of two separate divs

Tags: css

Why content 3 and content 4 are not two separate divs? How can I fix it only with css?
I would like the first red to be bellow the green ones and the second red to be bellow the first red.

JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/LsgsE/

HTML

```
<div class="left">TODO write content1</div>
<div class="left">TODO write content2</div>
<div >TODO write content3</div>
<div>TODO write content4</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
}
div:after {
clear: both;
display: block;
content: "";
height: 0px;
}
div.left {
float: left;
background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wit this:

```
div {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
clear: both;
}

div.left {
float: left;
background-color: green; 
clear: none;
}
```

Comment: This is working, but why the clearfix is doing this?

Comment: The first red div are behind the first green box, the text is shown below, but in fact the box is not there, so, if u use a clearfix the box should appear where you want. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LsgsE/7/ i've change the color of the third box to blue, can u see without use the clear? :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove height:0px and then they will not be overlapping.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong about that call. But it is clear:both that is the problem. So to get it to work you need to have float:left on your div css.

Comment: I would like the first red to be bellow the green ones and the second red to be bellow the first red.

Comment: Cant you just change the order of the divs?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding a wrapper to your divs:

```
<div id="upper_block">
    <div class="left">TODO write content1</div>
    <div class="right">TODO write content2</div>
    <div class="left">TODO write content3</div>
    <div class="right">TODO write content4</div>
</div>
```

And set new rules in your css:

```
    #upper_block {
      width: 400px;
    }
    div {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
    }
    div.right {
     float: right;
     background-color: green;
    }
    div.left{
     float: left;
     background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: I need them to be 2 on the first line, 1 on the second one and 1 on the third line.